# rails 4 new syntax changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can rewrite this line in rails 4. Not sure how?. Tried few ways but failed.

```
@news = @project.news.find(:all, :limit => 5, :include => [ :author, :project ], :order => "#{News.table_name}.created_on DESC")
```

Comment: @news = @project.news.order(-> { includes(:author, :project).limit(5).where("#{News.table_name}.created_on DESC")})

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
@news = @project.news.includes(:author, :project).order("#{News.table_name}.created_on DESC").limit(5)
```

or (I think it will works too)

```
@news = @project.news.includes(:author, :project).order(news: { created_on: :desc }).limit(5)
```

Comment: maxd!, Thanks for the answer. When I call @users_by_role.any?

it gives me Cannot visit Proc error  in the above line.
Any fixes?